# AppleScriptTask command not working in Excel 2016 for Mac VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript, excel-2016

I have an Excel file that makes heavy use of the MacScript command, which has been deprecated in Excel 2016.

I attempted to use the new AppleScriptTask command as explained in this StackOverflow thread: [The MacScript function is not working well in Office for Mac 2016! Any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949272/the-macscript-function-is-not-working-well-in-office-for-mac-2016-any-ideas)

I get run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument.

I'm not permitted by StackOverflow to post images because I'm new and don't have required "reputation." But images are useful to show exactly what I did. So here's a screenshot of my rejected question with embedded images: http://screencast.com/t/KDzY5kJXA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the Folder name is com.microsoft.Excel with uppercase E in Excel. I see that you have used a lowercase 'e' in Excel. 
You may have to remove com.microsoft.excel folder that you have created and create a new one. The code you have written is otherwise correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your suggestion next week and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: ramitarora, I really appreciate your help. I'm sorry for my long delay on confirming your solution. I'll definitely reply back.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple task like that, it should work.  However, in that AppleScript file, you cannot perform complex tasks such as calling a python file to download a youtube file by using
do shell script "python3 downloadYT.py"

even though I can run that command in a terminal or execute that AppleScript successfully.

Not sure what is the real limitation for applescripttask in Excel 365 for Mac?