# Using AppleScript to programmatically create an AppleScript file in plain text format

Tags: vba, macos, excel, applescript, ms-office

I have an AppleScript that is used to programmatically create a test script file in one of these Office 2016 app folders:

```
~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel
~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Word
~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Powerpoint
```

This is the test.scpt file content which is programmatically generated:

```
on handlerTest(thisPhrase)
    say thisPhrase
end handlerTest
```

This test.scpt file contains a single handler which speaks the phrase passed to it.

When the script is created in one of these folders, I cannot see the content of the script file in Finder and calling the handler from a Microsoft Office app using the new VBA AppleScriptTask causes the Office app to crash. I think the script is being created as a byte-compiled file because it cannot be viewed in Finder as plain text.

If I then copy the script file generated programmatically by my script creator script to the Documents folder, the plain-text content of the script is viewable in Finder.

Now, if I copy the script file from the Documents folder back to the corresponding com.microsoft folder (without modifying it), I can now see the plain-text content in Finder and calling the handler using the VBA AppleScriptTask function works as expected. I don't understand how the format is apparently changing due to copy/paste actions?

How can I programmatically create the script file in the com.microsoft.xyz folder in plain text format?

Here is my VBA procedure:

```
Sub TestScript()
    AppleScriptTask "test.scpt", "handlerTest", "hello world"
End Sub
```

Here is my example script creator script which programmatically creates a test.scpt file in the com.microsoft.Powerpoint scripting folder: (kudos to [eliteproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2948862/eliteproxy) for the [original source script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949272/the-macscript-function-is-not-working-well-in-office-for-mac-2016-any-ideas))

```
property theFolders : {"~/Library/'Application Scripts'/com.microsoft.Powerpoint"}

try
    tell application "Finder" to set targetFolder to (target of the front window) as alias
on error -- no window
    set targetFolder to (choose folder)
end try

# build a parameter string from the folder list
set {tempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, space}
set {theFolders, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {theFolders as text, tempTID}

do shell script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of targetFolder & "; mkdir -p " & theFolders

--Write the Script file if it does not exist
if ExistsFile("~/Library/'Application Scripts'/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/test.scpt") is false then
    tell application "Finder"
        --GET THE WORKING DIRECTORY FOR FILE COPY OF SCRIPT
        get folder of (path to me) as Unicode text
        set workingDir to POSIX path of result

        --Write the new script in the current working directory
        set textFile to workingDir & "test.scpt"

        --Delete script if it exists
        set posixPath to POSIX path of textFile as string
        do shell script "rm -rf \"" & posixPath & "\""

        --Create Script Interface file for Microsoft PowerPoint VBA Applications
        set fd to open for access textFile with write permission

        -- Create test handler which speaks the passed phrase parameter
        write "on handlerTest(thisPhrase)" & linefeed to fd as «class utf8» starting at eof
        write "say thisPhrase" & linefeed to fd as «class utf8» starting at eof
        write "end handlerTest" & linefeed to fd as «class utf8» starting at eof

        close access fd

        --Copy the script file into the MACOS-Specific 'safe' folder
        set fromPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (workingDir) & "test.scpt"
        set toPath to quoted form of "~/Library/'Application Scripts'/com.microsoft.Powerpoint"
        do shell script "cp -R " & fromPath & space & "~/Library/'Application Scripts'/com.microsoft.Powerpoint" with administrator privileges
    end tell
end if

--Delete the temp script file from the working directory
set posixPath to POSIX path of textFile as string
do shell script "rm -rf \"" & posixPath & "\""

--Provide confirmation
set theAlertTitle to "TEST"
set theAlertMsg to "The script has been successfully installed."
display alert theAlertTitle message theAlertMsg as informational buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" cancel button "OK"

--For use when checking if a file exists
on ExistsFile(filePath)
    tell application "System Events" to return (exists disk item filePath) and class of disk item filePath = file
end ExistsFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong in my interpretation of your question, but it appears as if you are looking to create file “Test.scpt” with your handler “handlerTest” as the code, in a folder named “com.microsoft.Excel” (for example).  If that is all you are looking to achieve, I believe this solution should work for you...

```
script theHandler
    on handlerTest(thisPhrase)
        say thisPhrase
    end handlerTest
end script

storeScript()

on storeScript()
    set thisScript to store script theHandler in (path to home folder as text) ¬
        & "Library:Application Scripts:com.microsoft.Excel:Test.scpt" replacing yes
end storeScript
```