# How to add files to a zip in VBA macro in macOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, zip

I am looking for a VBA macro code to add csv files to zip ***without using an AppleScript script***. I'm able to achieve this in Windows using the below code:

```
Set App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
App.Namespace(ZIPFILEPATH).CopyHere csvFileName
```

I'm looking for a similar method for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [MacScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/macscript-function) or [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) VBA function.

```
Dim shellCommand As String
Dim macScriptCommand As String
shellCommand = "zip -u -j " & zipPath & " " & csvPath
macScriptCommand = "do shell script " & """" & shellCommand & """"
```

You can either use `Shell (shellCommand)` or `MacScript (macScriptCommand)`. There are many flavors to `zip` and refer the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/zip#) on how you want to zip.
Note that `MacScript` is being deprecated as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949324/5524175).