# How can I get the duration in seconds of a MP4 with VBA in MacOs?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, applescript, mdls

I want to get the duration of an .mp4 video using VBA in MacOS.

```
Function GetMP4Length(filePath As String) As Double
    Dim durationOutput As String
    Dim durationInSeconds As Double
    
    ' Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)
    durationOutput = MacScript("do shell script ""mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds " & "'" & Replace("'/Users/simonsanchez/Downloads/My Folder/my file.mp4'", " ", "\\ ") & "'" & """")
    durationInSeconds = Val(Split(durationOutput, "=")(1))

    GetMP4FileLength = durationInSeconds
End Function
```

I'm getting the error: `Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)`

This is what I have, I've hard-coded the path as an example.

I've tried running this on ScriptEditor and it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to debug.print the value passed to `MacScript` and run it?

Comment: Why all the tags? What language are you wanting to do this with? If VBA, may I humbly ask why? This would be a few lines in Python, IIRC.  Why would you want to use this via Word??

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, I ran the code in MacOS Script Editor and it worked

Comment: @BruceWayne I need to make a Word macro that creates tables for images in a folder, each image has an .mp4 associated, and I need the duration

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so can't test, but maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949272/the-macscript-function-is-not-working-well-in-office-for-mac-2016-any-ideas/30949324#30949324

Comment: @TimWilliams Using AppleScriptTask worked great, thanks a lot!